# Extract range of NLME object

Tags: r, nlme

I have a NLME object with a correlation. I was wondering how I could extract the range of 
the correlation from the model. I'm running simulations, so I can't just read the summary, and get it manually.

So my model looks something like this:

```
library(MASS)
library(nlme)
lme(fixed=temp ~ time, random=~1|day,correlation=corExp(form=~time),data=beav1)
```

So I'd like to get the parameter of the correlation here.

Comment: Unless you have data too, I can't run that model to see what pops out. Can you use a built in data set? Can you show the summary to indicate which part you are trying to extract?

Comment: I've now changed it to a standard data set.

Comment: @shujaa beat me to it, but you have an answer now. Things are so much easier with a simple example.

Comment: @MrFlick Hope I wasn't poaching... though I'm pretty sure a week or so ago I had more reputation than you--by now you're about 50% ahead of me! :)

Comment: No worries @shujaa. I just like it when questions get answered. It doesn't have to be by me. And I admit I have gotten somewhat addicted to answering R questions on this site recently. Hopefully my interest will subside to a more reasonable level soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That took a lot of digging to find! I had to look at the code for `nlme:::print.summary.lme` to find `$modelStruct$corStruct`, and then at `nlme:::print.summary.corStruct` to get there.

This should work

```
library(datasets)
library(nlme)
mod <- lme(fixed = temp ~ time, random = ~1|day,
           correlation = corExp(form=~time), data=beaver1)

store_range <- coef(mod$modelStruct$corStruct, unconstrained = F)
```

Yielding

```
> store_range
   range 
58.82908
```

Comment: I was doing the same thing. I was just looking to see how the class change in the `print.summary.corStruct` changed the behavior of `coef` . Very interesting use of generic functions.

Comment: Yeah, I'm still confused by the necessity of that class change. Definitely gained an appreciation for the move to S4 classes in `lme4`.

Comment: You can shorten this a little bit -- you don't need `summary()`; `coef(mod$modelStruct$corStruct,unconstrained=FALSE)`

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks! Incorporated your suggestion. Thanks for maintaining `lme4` too, answering this question made me even more grateful for it.